# How do I find the intersection point from the Expanding Polytope Algorithm?

Tags: collision-detection

I've successfully implemented a 2D version of the GJK and EPA algorithms which gives me correct collision information, including collision normal and penetration depth.

What it doesn't give me however is the intersection point of the collision. And after much searching I haven't found a decent explanation of how, given the result of the EPA, I'm supposed to calculate the intersection point.

Could somebody please explain the algorithm for finding the intersection point?